# How to implement youtube bell button in android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am making an app in which user can subscribe to youtube channels. The subscribe button is working perfectly fine , I want to add one more button for bell icon button which we have in youtube. When ever user click bell button it should perform required functionality.

I found reference of anddroid youtube subscribe button here

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3

But i am unable to reference regarding bell icon(button). Can i program bell button code or is there any documentation i can check. If there is then please comment below